# Can be static reference to View memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am really new to Android development and I have read article about [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) on Android platform. I am not sure, if my following code...

```
public class TransactionDetailActivity extends Activity {

private Transaction transaction;

private TextView tvDetail; //static reference

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_transaction_detail);

    tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail); //init of reference
}
```

Can this storing into static reference cause any memory leaks after screen rotation on switching other Activities? If YES, how can I avoid it?

Thanks a lot for any help!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`private TextView tvDetail;` is not a static reference.

`private static TextView tvDetail;` is a static reference, but it's not desirable. Here you have an explanation: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Sometimes, we developers set variables as static to avoid recreating objects... something like this in you case:

```
// DON'T DO THIS! FOR THE LOVE OF GOD! 
if( tvDetail == null ){
    tvDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
}
```

But this is wrong in android development, since each time the `onCreate` method is called, new references to the UI elements are created too. So, just try to avoid the code above.

Comment: I don't think there's enough "FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DON'T DO THIS" in that post, so I'd like to add more. DON'T DO THAT! STOP! NO! BAD! DO NOT MAKE STATIC REFERENCES TO UI ELEMENTS!

Comment: What if you have a indeterminate progressbar in a custom header that is shared by all activities, and you want any thead to change its state from whatever activity you are?

Comment: Why would you share an **indeterminate** among activities? It won't represent any performance improvement.

Comment: Adding to this: a View holds a reference to a Context object (which btw comes in VERY handy at times to reduce holding onto contexts. View.getContext() is quite nice). Context references are a very common source of Android memory leaks. On top of that, if the screen for view gets recreated, there may be a chance that the reference to the view may be pointing to the wrong data structure and never gets found again. That can cause a NullPointerException, and those suck

Comment: Suppose I want to use just a single progess dialog across entire application that is visible when any api hit is called,how would I achieve it without leaking memory?